# Strange C++ Circling Errors with string manipulation

Tags: c++, string, for-loop

I am searching a `std::string` for certain letters so I am using:

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++)
...
```

But I then get the error:

> > Error 2   error C3867: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::length': function call missing argument list; use '&std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::length' to create a pointer to member

So I put:

```
for (int i = 0; i < &word.length; i++)
...
```

And then get the error:

> > Error 2   error C2276: '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression

How can I fix this and search the string? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just missing the `()` after `length`.

[`std::string::length()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/length) is a function which has no parameters.